# TexStudio: Spell-check is suggesting that I delete random words, how do I disable this?

Tags: texstudio, editors, spelling

I would rather not have green squiggle lines from these suggestions.

[image: Here's what it looks like.]

Comment: Try turning your grammar checker off in "options".

Comment: I would like to keep the spell checking on but without the squiggly lines shown above.

Comment: Grammar checking and spell checking are two different things. Leave spell check on, turn off just grammar checking.

Comment: Oh, I see. You're right, turning off the grammar checker solved the problem but point remains that the weird grammar checker behavior shown above is a flaw in TexStudio.

Comment: Cedric, why don't you go ahead and post turning off grammar as an answer to your own question.  You can then accept it as the correct answer.  That way other people with the same problem can use this question as a reference.  As far as being a flaw, to my knowledge there really is no such thing as an "intelligent" grammar checker, the state of the art is not very advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unchecking the grammar checker in the editor tab of configure TexStudio makes the squiggles go away. It seems the grammar checker is dysfunctional.